# Avoid radcombobox suggest list from being collapsed

Tags: winforms, user-controls, telerik

I have a RadDropDownList in suggestappend mode and a usercontrol as keyboard, this have buttons with ControlStyles.Selectable = false. the MouseUp event fires a SendKeys.Send(key).
The thing is when I focus in the RadDropDownList and write with my keyboard (UserControl) the suggest list appears for a milisecond and desappear.
I tried to control the popup event but it seems to have nothing to do with the suggest list.
how can i keep it opened showing suggestions until user leaves the RadDropDownList?

Comment: Could you please specify precisely which control (RadComboBox or RadDropDownList or just a ComboBox) are you using and the version of the assemblies?

Comment: Is a RadDropDownList, sorry about that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to access the auto complete suggest popup and cancel the closure of the popup:

```
  radDropDownList1.DropDownListElement.AutoCompleteSuggest.DropDownList.PopupClosing += DropDownList_PopupClosing;

  . . .    

  void DropDownList_PopupClosing(object sender, Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadPopupClosingEventArgs args)
  {
        args.Cancel = true;
  }
```